# Raspbian wifi connection problems

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

My raspberry pi is freaking out. I did the setup right in wifi config, but for some reason it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting over and over again. What do I do?

Comment: It happens with me when the signal is weak. The WiFi module has a small antenna and can't be too far from the router.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different power adapter or a powered USB hub.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue. Your power adapter isn´t providing sufficient current. Try one with at least 1,5A output